# How to pass this.varible to HTML within class extends React.Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, react-class-based-component

I am currently using the react-youtube library within one of my react objects. It contains some data that I would like to display on the screen.

```
import YouTube from 'react-youtube';

class MediaCompnent extends React.Component {
  _onReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
    this.myTitle = event.target.videoTitle;
  }

  render() {
    const opts = {
      height: '450',
      width: '650',
      playerVars: {
        autoplay: 1,
      },
    };

    const activeTitle = this.myTitle;

    return (
      <div className="media-area">
        <div className="video-box">
          <div className="video-title">{activeTitle}</div>
          <YouTube
            videoId={this.props.activeMediaUrl}
            opts={opts}
            onReady={this._onReady}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="media-description-area">
          {this.props.activeDescription}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MediaCompnent;
```

Currently I am passing the **event.target** to the **_onReady** function so that it can be read every time that the video is refreshed or one of the props changes. **event.target** returns an object.

I am attempting to read the title data and pass it into **this.myTitle** I am then trying to store it in a **const** within my **render** function and then setting this title within my HTML.

Currently, the activeTitle will not display to screen, but I am managing to print the desired string to the console. What is necessary to pass the variable correctly in order to display in the HTML?

Thanks

Comment: How does the current behavior differ from the desired behavior?

Comment: it wont display on screen

Comment: You have to make it a `state` variable otherwise it won't automatically re-render when the variable changes.

Comment: I am trying, but the error stated is.... React Hook "useState" cannot be called in a class component. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mateusz Rorat has the right idea but there is more to it.

You need to have a `constructor` initialize `this.state` and you need to wire up the `_onReady` handler a bit differently so that the `this` variable refers to the class instance's `this` even inside the `_onReady` handler function. Also you need to retrieve `myTitle` slightly differently since now it's stored inside `this.state` (not inside `this` directly).

```
import React from 'react';
import YouTube from 'react-youtube';

class MediaComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  _onReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
    this.setState({
      myTitle: event.target.videoTitle,
    });
  }

  render() {
    const opts = {
      height: '450',
      width: '650',
      playerVars: {
        autoplay: 1,
      },
    };

    const activeTitle = this.state.myTitle;

    return (
      <div className="media-area">
        <div className="video-box">
          <div className="video-title">{activeTitle}</div>
          <YouTube
            videoId={this.props.activeMediaUrl}
            opts={opts}
            onReady={(event) => this._onReady(event)}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="media-description-area">
          {this.props.activeDescription}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MediaComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

use setState() and refer this.state.myTitle. But I am bit worried that if you do that rerender will trigger that YouTube component to rereder

```
  _onReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
    this.setState({myTitle:  event.target.videoTitle});
  }
```

Comment: this crashes the program unfortunately